# Difference between LH and ICSH

Tags: endocrinology, terminology

Are **Luteinizing hormone** and **Interstitial Cell Stimulating Hormone(ICSH)** the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as online dictionaries ([Medical Dictionary](http://www.online-medical-dictionary.org/definitions-i/icsh-(interstitial-cell-stimulating-hormone).html), [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interstitial-cell-stimulating%20hormone)) and a popular-scientific site on hormones ([Your Hormones](http://www.yourhormones.info/hormones/luteinising_hormone.aspx)) go, LH and ICSH are the same. ICSH mainly pops up in the older literature; e.g., [Lostron & Johnson (1966)](http://press.endocrine.org/doi/pdf/10.1210/endo-79-5-991) and [Louvet *et al*. (1975)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1122882). My understanding is that LH is currently the more accepted term for the hormone.

I get the impression that historically, LH has been used in relation to female reproduction and ICSH to the male reproductive systems. In males, LH stimulates Leydig cells in the testes to produce testosterone. In females it stimulates the ovarian follicles to produce oestradiol, and it induces ovulation.

<sub>**References**

**-** [Lostron & Johnson, *Endocrinology* (1966); **79**: 991](http://press.endocrine.org/doi/pdf/10.1210/endo-79-5-991)

**-** [Louvet *et al*. *Endocrinology* (1975); **96**(5): 1179-86](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1122882)</sub>